# Meteor AngularJS application not loading directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a simple directive, `<my-directive></my-directive>`

client/scripts/directives/myDirective.directive.js:

```
angular
  .module('myApp')
  .directive('myDirective', myDirective);

function myDirective() {
  return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    scope: {
      data: '='
    },
    templateUrl: "'/client/templates/partials/liftOwnerConfirmedRiders.html'",
  };
}
```

client/templates/partials/myDirective.html:

```
<p>Hi. How are you?</p>
```

Why will the text not show when I use the directive in another page?

Comment: Your question isn't really clear.  For starters, you have the `templateUrl` for your directive set to `'/client/templates/partials/liftOwnerConfirmedRiders.html'`, but you are showing the contents of `'client/templates/partials/myDirective.html'`, which I assume is a missed change when trying to make the example.  Beyond that, you aren't showing where these are being used, what `ng-app` context the directive is under on the other page, and where the script for this directive is loaded in your HTML.

Answer (score 1):

I had troubles with displaying meteor-angular directives, but they were gone when I've added ['angular-meteor'] to my module definition:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['angular-meteor'])
```

Also, my templateUrl differs from yours. It starts without slash :

```
templateUrl: 'client/templates/tabset.html'
```

Answer (score 0):

This most commonly happens to me when I fail to reference the directive JS (and any dependencies) in the page. If you don't load the directive in the page where it's used then it will just be ignored by the browser and won't even throw an error in the console (unless it's missing a dependency too).

As Claies writes, we need more context if you want more than generic responses like this.